# Apache DirectoryIndex, mod_jk, and trailing slashes

Tags: apache, tomcat, mod-jk

I appreciate any help with this Apache mod_jk configuration (not my area of expertise).

I have setup mod_jk to front-end a tomcat service (kdxwiki), and that's working fine.  However, I'm unable to get the JkUnMount directive to fully bypass an apache web site (websvn) that I co-host on the server.  By fully, I mean that I am only able to reach the apache website when I leave on the trailing /.  If I leave off the trailing /, the browser is instead redirected to tomcat.

I'm pretty sure I need to make a rewrite rule, but I've had no luck with the syntax.

**Works With Slash**: http;//hostname/websvn/

**Doesn't Work Without Slash**: http://kdxwiki/websvn is redirected to http://kdxwiki:8081/websvn/

**workers.properties**

```
workers.java_home=/usr/java/default
ps=/
worker.list=worker1
worker.worker1.type=ajp13
worker.worker1.port=8010
worker.worker1.host=kdxwiki
worker.worker1.lbfactor=1
```

**jk.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName kdxwiki:8081
   ServerAlias kdxwiki.inside.company.corp
   JkMount  /* worker1
   JkUnMount /websvn worker1
   JkUnMount /*websvn worker1
   JkUnMount /websvn/* worker1
</VirtualHost>
```

**websvn.conf**

```
Alias /websvn /usr/share/websvn
DocumentRoot /usr/share/websvn
<Directory /usr/share/websvn/>
   Options +Indexes
   Options +FollowSymLinks
   allow from all
</Directory>
```

**httpd.conf**

```
#
# Mod_jk settings
#
# Load mod_jk module
LoadModule    jk_module  modules/mod_jk.so
# Where to find workers.properties
JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
# Where to put jk logs
JkLogFile     logs/mod_jk.log
# Set the jk log level [debug/error/info]
JkLogLevel    emerg
# Select the log format
JkLogStampFormat "[%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y] "
# JkOptions indicate to send SSL KEY SIZE,
JkOptions     +ForwardKeySize +ForwardURICompat -ForwardDirectories
#JkOptions +ForwardURICompatUnparsed
# JkRequestLogFormat set the request format
JkRequestLogFormat     "%w %V %T"
# Where to put jk shared memory
JkShmFile     /etc/httpd/logs/jk-runtime-status
```

Comment: this will get better responses on serverfault.com